# Ubuntu 14.04 Live disk enters low graphics mode, then screen goes black

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, live-cd, livedvd

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 on a computer I just put together with a live disk.  I get to the screen letting choose from try ubuntu, and the installer.  Regardless of which one I pick it says it must enter low graphics mode, then says the monitor must restart, but the screen just goes black.  I'm thinking I might have to try the install with the graphics card removed from the computer and try the install, but I'm not sure.  I have a gtx750 card, an intel i7 skylake cpu, 16g corsair vengence ram, and a z170a msi motherboard

Answer (score 0):

Eric,
Edit the start menu by pressing 'e' for edit and placing a command line inside it to load the CRT to 800X600 or 600X480 the low graphics mode before your (above mentioned) screen for 'choosing' appears - so that either option will work after selecting them.
Examples:

LOAD CRT = 600 X 480

or

LOAD CRT = 800 X 600

Save that and let it boot those commands, then come to your screen:

Try Ubuntu / 
Install Ubuntu

Then select either option - and the monitor should allow you to continue with trying Ubuntu or the Installation process of Ubuntu.